# Video concatenation excruciatingly slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I tried using OpenShot Video Editor to concatenate a few videos of a vacation I recently went on. However, the process seems to be taking forever; I really do not want to leave the computer on all day. The files combined are about two gigs in size. I would like to join them together into a single file, without modifying the quality (I guess "copy the codec").

Even though I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I consider myself somewhat of a beginner in respect to my skills with Linux. I have attempted to use FFMPEG, to no avail.

It would be great if someone on this site can please assist me and guide me in what I should do.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So much content, and not a single word, that describes your hardware.  In any event if your trying to concatenate 2 GB worth of video its going to take awhile.

Comment: Not really. I have routinely concatenated hundreds of files from a HLS playlist into a 2 or 3 GB single video and it took around 2 minutes at most, usually less. This is in codec copy mode, of course. Disk I/O is the bottleneck here, and on modern SATA drives and buses, should be fairly fast.

Comment: @Ramhound hey sorry for not responding sooner, and for leaving out that info. I'm using a Samsung R580 laptop with an i3 processor and 8gb of RAM.